# Find the difference between Start Date and previous end date in python grouped and shifted by a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, date-comparison

I have the following dataframe

| Station | Sub station | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | X | 1/11/2023 | 8/31/2023 |
| Alpha | X | 9/11/2023 | 10/31/2023 |
| Alpha | Y | 11/10/2023 | 12/31/2023 |
| Beta | Z | 1/10/2023 | 2/10/2023 |
| Beta | Z | 2/11/2023 | 3/10/2023 |
| Beta | Z | 9/1/2023 | 10/1/2023 |

[image: Orginal_df]

For a given Station and sub station pair I would like to get the number of days between the start date and the previous end date grouped by the station and sub station.

Ideal result would be:

| Station | Sub station | Start Date | End Date | Diff From Prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | X | 1/11/2023 | 8/31/2023 | NaN |
| Alpha | X | 9/11/2023 | 10/31/2023 | 11 |
| Alpha | Y | 11/10/2023 | 12/31/2023 | NaN |
| Beta | Z | 1/10/2023 | 2/10/2023 | NaN |
| Beta | Z | 2/11/2023 | 3/10/2023 | 1 |
| Beta | Z | 9/1/2023 | 10/1/2023 | 175 |

[image: Expected_result]

I am not sure how to do this. Any guidance is appreciated! Thank you.